# Ionic: Can't loop through all firebase records

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2

My main objective is to loop through all the records inside the request table in firebase to get the user key value. When I loop through all the records I am only getting the first record in the table.

My code:

```
openMapPage()
  {

     this.request.forEach(i => {
     let r = 0;
     console.log(i[r].$key);
     r++ 
   });

  this.navCtrl.push(MapPage)

   }
```

My console is only printing 1 user key value only:

[image]

My firebase database:

[image]

Comment: [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your "this.request" points to parent object. Try this one:

```
let process = this.request.subscribe(records => {
// your logic
 records.forEach(record => {
  console.log(record.$key);
 });

});
// Remove watch if you wish
process.unsubscribe();
```

Comment: Nope it doesn't

Comment: this is at the constructor,  this.request = angFire.list('/request');

Comment: are you sure about your firebase config pointing to correct database?